# Заполнение области сферами

Tags: c++

Существуют ли готовые алгоритмы по заполнению области сферами различных радиусов?

Comment: для графического изображения прогуглите, может и найдете...

Comment: Задача об упаковке шаров, да? Ну, надо посмотреть статьи по этой теме, думаю, там будет...

Comment: в статьях стоит задача о плотной упаковке сфер одинаковых радиусов, мне же плотная упаковка не требуется, имеются ли статьи с реализованным алгоритмом по засыпке?